# angular cli doesn't create the Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

For below command:

```
ng generate component mycomponent
```

it is just consoling this errored message as below:

> Cannot read property 'NullLogger' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'NullLogger' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the latest angular cli with this command: npm install --save @angular/cli@latest

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9303 it seems to be a version issue :

```
Please first uninstall all versions and clear the cache, and after install:
ng install -g @angular/cli@1.4.10
```

Comment: thank you i solve the issue is that i have a global version 1.7.0 and local version 1.4 this inequality make the issue. for that i change the local version by using "npm uninstall -g angular-cli",  "npm cache clean --force",  and "npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest"

Answer (score 0):

Below package.json with corresponding dependencies should work:

```
{
      "name": "angular-tour-of-heroes",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "license": "MIT",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^4.3.1",
        "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
        "@types/jquery": "^2.0.45",
        "angular2-tooltip": "^3.1.0",
        "angular2-websocket-service": "^0.5.3",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2.1",
        "ng2-stomp-service": "^1.2.2",
        "ng2-toastr": "^4.0.1",
        "ngx-toastr": "^8.7.3",
        "queueing-subject": "^0.1.1",
        "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
        "sockjs-client": "1.0.0",
        "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
        "tslib": "^1.9.2",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
        "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.33",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
        "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
        "angular-ide": "^0.9.22",
        "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
        "karma": "~1.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.1.0",
        "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
        "tslint": "~4.5.0",
        "typescript": "~2.2.0"
      }
    }
```

Place this package.json in your project root and just run the below command again:

```
npm install
```

and then

```
ng generate component mycomponent
```